# Tutorial or quick 'how to' with numbers and strings inside in loops

Tags: javascript, string, variables, numbers

I'm getting unexpected results with the code below:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var text = "something";
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        text += "The number is " + i + "<br>";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to loop through a block of code five times.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

The result is:

```
somethingThe number is 0
The number is 1
The number is 2
The number is 3
The number is 4
```

Why don't I get the result below?

```
somethingThe number is 0
somethingThe number is 1
somethingThe number is 2
somethingThe number is 3
somethingThe number is 4
```

Comment: Why do you *expect* to get “something” at the start of every line, seeing as it’s not added inside the loop?

Comment: it is, text=something...well I think it is OR what's text += doing then? Can you explain that then please?

Comment: well, it's simple: you start with `"something"` and then add `"The number is " + i + "<br>"` on each step; you don't add any more `"something"`. To get the result you've described, you have to start with `""` (empty string) and add `"something" + "The number is " + i + "<br>"` in your loop

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's simple: you start with `"something"` and then add `"The number is " + i + "<br>"` on each step; you don't add any more `"something"`. To get the result you've described, you have to start with `""` (empty string) and add `"something" + "The number is " + i + "<br>"` in your loop, pretty straight-forward:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var text = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        text += "something" + "The number is " + i + "<br>";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to loop through a block of code five times.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```